# Как достать user_id для функции restrict_chat_member используя команду /mute как ответ на комментарий пользователя для TELEGRAM бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

Я пытался реализовать простую команду /mute, используя которую как ответ на любой комментарий пользователя в чате, бот будет выдавать (этому пользователю) мут на 2 минуты.

Но к сожалению, я не знаю как достать нужный user_id для функции restrict_chat_member, который по моей теории находиться по пути "message.reply_to_message.json.from.id"

Пример кода:

```
import telebot
import time
from time import time
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["mute"])
def mut(message):
    bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, USER_ID , until_date=time()+120)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Администратор кинул вас в мут на 2м', reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
```

Собственно что писать на месте USER_ID я и не понимаю.

Comment: Как говорит ответ telegram - `method is available only for supergroups`. Это означает, что данный метод работает только в группах, в которую добавили бота, и он имеет соответствующие привилегии. В user_id нужно передать идентификатор пользователя - а в `message.chat.id` -  должен быть идентификатор группы (отрицательное `int` число). Точнее, если писать сообщение в группе то в `messgae.chat.id` и будет id группы. В обычных чатах с пользователем, как я понимаю, это не будет работать. Можете почитать об этом здесь - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#restrictchatmember

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["mute"])
def mute(message):
    print(message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
    bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.from_user.id, until_date=time.time() + 120)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Администратор кинул вас в мут на 2м', reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
```